# CSS Property Max-Width Functionality Confusion

Tags: html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_responsive2

According to W3, max-width specifies the element can go no larger than its set value, and if specified as a percentage it will be a percentage of the containing block. However, in the linked example it is at 100% so shouldn't the max-width be the value of the body (it's containing block)?

My second question is this, why do images with max-width change become responsive? Is it just something you accept or is there some technical reason behind it? A max-width means it cannot exceed a certain size, but why would that make images shrink with the window? An image with auto width and height does not do this, so is there some special max-width feature that allows this or am I missing something?

Comment: please focus on your question and use a separate post(question) for other questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, max width 100% specifies maximum width inside the container it can get .
Secondly, for image if you set an image normally I mean without any height or width attribute it will have its original size (i.e. if an image is 640x360px it will take that size in browser) but when you specify max-width: 100% attribute it takes the space within the container availabe if that is lesser than image width, but as the attribute name suggests it is maximum width it can take but the minimum width is bound by actual image width.

Comment: thanks buddy, I think I have wrapped my head around it